# How to traverse a dynamic array using karate?

Tags: karate, intuit-partner-platform

I am hitting an api -> `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/library/?book_id=2,5,13`
The response of the api is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "2":{
                "rack": 219,
                "price": 360,
                "title": "book1"
            },
        "5":{
                "rack": 309,
                "price": 230,
                "title": "book2"
            },
        "13":{
                "rack": 112,
                "price": 200,
                "title": "book3"
            }
    },
    "status_code": 200
}
```

the keys 2,5,13 are variable depending on the api param.

I wrote the following code=>

```
Feature: Verify Library API
    Scenario: Verify book prices 
        * def id1 = 2 
        * def id2 = 5 
        * def id3 = 13 
        Given url 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/library/?book_id='+ id1 +',' + id2 + ',' + id3 
        When method get 
        Then status 200 
        * def id1_price = $.data.#(id1).price 
        * assert id1_price == 360
```

I wasn't able to get the value of the price of book1 in the variable, which resulted in the assertion failure. How do I access the price using the variable "id1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have dynamic JsonPath expressions, use the [`karate.jsonPath()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#jsonpath-filters) API. try this:

```
* def id1_price = karate.jsonPath(response, "$.data." + id1 + ".price")
```

Comment: Do you have any example for the same?

Comment: @AineshPatidar follow the link