# karate fetch response of json using variable

Tags: karate

In my response json, there is a field of date which is changed as per day.

Here is my json:

```
{
    "data": {
        "0000164": {
            "2019-04-03": {
                "VALUE": 26
            }
        }
    },
    "status": 200
}
```

to fetch data from json i am using command :`$.data.0000164.2019-04-03.OAK`

but i want to generalise the case.I have the date saved in a variable

Example:

```
* def date = '2019-04-03'
* def hotel = '0000164'
```

want to fetch response by replacing hotel and date field with these values

```
$.data.hotel.date.OAK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [jsonPath](https://github.com/intuit/karate#jsonpath-filters) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50855425/10791639

```
* def date = '2019-04-03'
* def hotel = '0000164'
* def answer = karate.jsonPath(response, "$.data." + hotel + "." + date + ".OAK")
```

Comment: simple JS may work also `* def answer = response.data[hotel][date].OAK`